# How can I combine two MySQL rows as one and count results?

Tags: php, mysql, count

Basically, I have a database with 10 exam types. Each type has two parts, and is updated as pass or fail. I need to list the total count of exams that have not been completed (both parts passed).

I've tried this and it returns the count if either part shows pass, not both.

```
$query = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM candidate_exams
       WHERE gID='1' AND canID='%d' AND exResult='y'
       GROUP BY gEID",
    (int) $canID
);
$result = $con->query($query);
$rowCount = 10 - mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

- 'gID' is an identifier that tracks what group these 10 exams come from,
- 'canID' is a candidate identifier,
- 'gEID' is an exam type.

Comment: can you visualize your db tables?

Comment: When asking a question, please try to be as clear as possible: show us some (pseudo)data, example code, what you've tried and what not, and also check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've tried to select where record shows pass and group by exam type. That counts if either part is passed but not if both are.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabele WHERE type_a = 'fail' OR type_b = 'fail'
```

something like this?
It would help a lot to see your table structure to be able to answer this question properly.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer.